# .cs is a binary file instead of a text file

Tags: c#, visual-studio

So, I opened my project in visual studio to find that the code for one of my forms looks like this :

### loginForm.cs

```
í}ksâH²ö÷ØÿPÑÝ}¢¡w8Ó‹±ÝÍßÆØžw£»cBHh¬Û¨$lvgÿû›Y’¸„AX¥¶÷œi„*Ÿ|²²²nYå’Ô(”àÿê7R¹]j¶+ÕbS’
¥Z»T"}ª¸še’¡å»óÙ¡ä7Ë¹g®Œ—?[S?Õjú2¡ƒKŸ¤rQ*–>§éê§J¹Q®V«ˆeã>]SÊŒþ­¼±Tx×Àb”Œ-æª_Kµz©ô|½t´‘fÊ®åü³ÞlÔ óŸŽéPöt÷;9ö[3G„ÊŽ>%º5bí¿ÿíoþGNøEÍÔ\~‡€øŽK
ÁßZaÊÍÒa
Û   raÏVe—¢Î@a*J¥XæPyUÿþLiš9´¶-ê³®
bÈºn)däAYŒ˜–Ù¶å¸T-F«€š*!›U0çƒµgÖh„°=FÊÌ%¶ìŽÛðQgôï)v3¦d`9òGÐ†í·ÞÙ€ùÈ¦ªS•¦äÎ»–“zÙ=Ð§&ëÚ¿¡Š3©|˜òˆ:iÕõ‡š.y€ê‡ºU5ê¦åLÛ¤ÛþvåX#G6ŽeWþæ×ÓoüÝé+Û¡²zeY:yÐLÕz`}WVî{†AU
Œ¾k˜Ø'â:^ZÚ>•5§¯Œ©êéÔùN®Ír4*9€º«DC« 2xª -¦T(z¹_=êÑâÄ0@½K€hë½¿Ì€J ²µÉÖ¿ù@Ü©MAKC€N4Dô Ð| šKß¨6£¥ƒ(±yh%n¯ºgÖ|…IõÃjìÌ2G72»ßVoKÏGk`ìI}sGÒÊ®2æŽ‹—Eè£By8ÀÀ‹1y ó–*õb¯éHc.…F›b
```

Visual studio is saying that **loginForm.cs** is a binary file instead of a text file.

If anyone could help me in recovering the original code, that would be great!

Comment: @JeffMercado It has to do with tools used for programming messing up your source code, no?

Comment: @Dronz: Ok, so suppose it was... then what? He's asking how to recover the original files. If he doesn't have them in version control or any backups, then it's gone. You can't just "uncorrupt" a file. If this was on topic... how would you propose he go about recovering the files? Any solution would be outside the realm of programming or using the tools used for programming, it's now just a data recovery problem.

Comment: Have you activated the windows File History?

Comment: @JeffMercado It's not necessarily just gone. For instance, there are some details about Visual Studio itself that may help - it's autorecovery behavior and where it stores the previous version, for instance, as described in the article on this subject in the link in the answer I offered.

Comment: Ransomware infection, perhaps?  On a machine that has the ability to write to where you have your code stored.  (If it were on your machine it would be telling you how to pay.)

Comment: @LorenPechtel No, only one file was affected for some reason. I seem to be having some kind of error when trying to rollback my system.

Comment: Then I would suspect file system corruption, this might not even be your file at all.  In the old days I would search the disk for a piece of text that I knew to be in the file, it's been a long time since I've tried to do anything like that and I have no idea what the tools are like these days.

Answer (score 2):

I got this today after updating to VS2017
The complaint was levelled against an icon file in my project.
It'd always been there and worked happily in VS2013
The build action had somehow become "Compile" and so it was saying that it couldn't compile the .ico file - it would expect some kind of text file - a .cpp, or .cs etc. to compile.
I'm not sure if I simply changed this by accident, nothing seemed to indicate that my project file had changed under source control, but if it's something that changes simply by virtue of upgrade from VS2013 to 2017, then it's a "gotcha" to look out for.
I changed the build action (back to) "Content" (as I suspect it had been) and "Copy if newer" and all built okay.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know what might have corrupted or overwritten the file?

If you don't have a version to revert to in your source control system, there may be a previous version still in your file system, or you may have some luck with other file editors or decompiling, depending on how complex the file was.

Here is article that suggests several approaches for recovering corrupted cs source files in Visual Studio:

https://www.samnoble.co.uk/2014/11/30/visual-studio-crashes-and-a-corrupted-cs-file/

Comment: I had a system restore setup, thanks for reminding me! I'll try that out and come back with results.

Comment: I tried the system restore, it failed unfortunately. Windows couldn't tell me why it failed and the file is still corrupted. I can redo the form but it is just a lot of time wasted.